# Performances in accessing Associative Array Object via variable or hard-coded string

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

One of my "just curious about" questions here... I was wondering, from a performance point of view, do you know if it makes any substantial difference to access an associative array object specific element with a longer hard-coded string over (as in more commonly practice) a shortened name string variable that I'd have there anyway?

Take as an example the case this is going to happen while looping the elements:

```
myAAO = { entry-name1: value, entry-name2: value, long-entryX-name: value, entry-nameN: value, ... }; // my associative array object that may contain a lot of entries and may or may not contain the 'long-entryX-name' one
for (let i in myAAO) {
  if (i != 'long-entryX-name') {
    //do same things with all others myAAO[i] entries that aren't 'long-entryX-name' one
  } else {
    // I need to do specific things with this entry that are different than in all the other ones and I know i == 'long-entryX-name' already so will I have any good reason to retrieve the value doing:
    myAAO['long-entryX-name'];
    // over the usual
    myAAO[i];
    // or there wouldn't be any significant difference to prefer the former?
// I know the latter is less prone to misspelling the name for sure and I'd go with it...
  }
}
```

Comment: [Race your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: That is severely overthinking optimization. But when curiosity gets to you...create a perf test